# How to fixed image dimension when zoom out page using css?

Tags: html, css, image

How to fixed image dimension when zoom out page using css ?

for example in this case is fiverr.com

when zoom page 25%

http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iy/150803122836.png

and then when zoom page 100% (normal)

http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ij/150803122858.png

How to fixed image dimension like this case ?

I tried to do many time but not work (image dimension not fixed).

How can i do that ?

Comment: @ rick jan cawaling -- first i tried set style of image to `min-height: 500px` and it's not work.

Comment: and `<div  style='background:url(my-image.jpg)'></div>`

Comment: @robertqewerutiyo Try doing this instead <div style='background:url(my-image.jpg) center cover'></div>

Comment: @Pa3k.m -- google chrome inspections element invalid property value.

Comment: @robert qewerutiyo `<div style='background-image:url(my-image.jpg) ; background-position:center; background-size:cover;'></div>`

Answer (score 1):

To make background image fit the entire width of the page there are some option in CSS. In this case you should try background-size cover.

**CSS**

```
.background {
  background-size:cover;
}
```